# Is measuring connection time like this good practice for php? Is there a better way?

Tags: php, loops, curl

I need to measure the response time of a webservice multiple times in a row, I used to do it like this for a single connection (without the loop) but it doesn´t feel right to do it like this now, although it seems to be working. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```
$servername = "x.x.x.x";
$username = "xxx";
$password = "xxx";
$db = "xxx";

for($i=0; $i<10;++$i){

  $ch = $_SESSION['cURL'];
  $time_pre = microtime(true);
  $data = curl_exec($ch);
  $time_pro = microtime(true);
  $exec_time[$i] = $time_pro - $time_pre;
 }

$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $db);

//Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error){
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Madrid');
$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
var_dump($date);

for($i=0; $i<10;++$i){
    $query = "INSERT INTO DB(time, date) VALUES('$exec_time[$i]', '$date')";
    $result2=mysqli_query($conn, $query);
}
```

Comment: I think your question is better suited for Code Review: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ :-)

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-getinfo.php `curl_getinfo($ch)['total_time']`, there is also curl_multi http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-exec.php which will be 10x faster

Comment: @SketchyCoder Didn´t know about that one! Will check it as soon as I can and change the question if it´s the case. Thanks ^^

Comment: @LawrenceCherone The curl_multi function looks great. If you want to place it as an aswer, I´ll wait a couple hours to let other people answer and select yours if there is nothing better ^^ TY!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up using Lawrence Cherone suggestion in the comments. It´s faster and cleaner that what I was using.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-exec.php

```
//add the two handles
curl_multi_add_handle($mh,$ch1);
curl_multi_add_handle($mh,$ch2);

$active = null;
//execute the handles
do {
    $mrc = curl_multi_exec($mh, $active);
} while ($mrc == CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM);

while ($active && $mrc == CURLM_OK) {
    if (curl_multi_select($mh) != -1) {
        do {
            $mrc = curl_multi_exec($mh, $active);
        } while ($mrc == CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM);
    }
}

//close the handles
curl_multi_remove_handle($mh, $ch1);
curl_multi_remove_handle($mh, $ch2);
```